# CSS negative margin overlap not working on child elements

Tags: html, css, language-lawyer

I'm struggling with some basic CSS layout flow. If I have two divs one after another, where the second div has a negative top margin, I'd expect it to overlap the preceding div.

However, I'm finding that while the first div is indeed overlapped, its contents are not.

```
<div style="background:green;height:20px;">
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span>
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span>
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span>
</div>
<div style="background:yellow;height:20px;margin-top:-10px;">
</div>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/xwghd5r2/

---

This seems to run counter to the principles of the basic stacking order:

From https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/:

> Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they
>   appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level
>   appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always
>   appear on top of elements with default static positioning.
>
> Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top
>   of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than
>   element B.

---

**NOTE:** I'm not looking for a fix by changing the `position` attribute-  I'm just trying to understand why this current flow is happening with the default static positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The painting order is defined in [Appendix E](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html#painting-order).

When the browser paints these contents, it will first paint background of the blocks

> 4. For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent:
>
>    1. background color of element.

And backgrounds of inline-blocks will be painted in front of the ones from the blocks:

> 7. Otherwise: first for the element, then for all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order:
>
>    2. Otherwise, for each line box of that element:
>
>       1. For each box that is a child of that element, in that line box, in tree order:
>
>          1. background color of element.

Note that the contents of the second block will still be painted in front of the inline-blocks:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
div + div {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #0ff;
}
span {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>HELLO</span>
  <span>HELLO</span>
  <span>HELLO</span>
</div>
<div>█ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: relative`, and research position and `z-index`.

https://jsfiddle.net/xwghd5r2/1/

Comment: but i don't know why, just know that is true

Answer (score 0):

You want yellow div to overlap first div content? Add: `position:relative` on yellow div.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/xwghd5r2/3/

```css
nav, #down {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav style="background:green;height:20px;">
  <li style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</li>
  <li style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</li>
  <li style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</li>
</nav>
<div id="down" style="background:yellow;width:100%;height:20px;margin-top:-10px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a parent elements child has always a higher index.

Let's discus that based on your example:

```
<div style="background:green;height:20px;"> <-- index: 1
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span> <-- index: 2
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span> <-- index: 2
  <span style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:2px;">HELLO</span> <-- index: 2
</div>
<div style="background:yellow;height:20px;margin-top:-10px;"> <-- index: 1
</div>
```

So, according to your example, your `span` elements will get displayed in foreground, compared to both of your `div` elements. Also on the other hand, the second `div` element will overlap your first one. That's because they have the same index value.

In other words your browser will render your markup according to an elements index value (your own ones will of course be preferred) and (if the index is the same) by the order in which it has been placed inside of your markup.

***Note:*** Any style change of an element **can** result in a different behaivour, if it's not your browsers default one.